# Issue with string concatenation in C

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

This is regarding `C` programming language.

I have a large number of 2D arrays (`sizes are not fixed`). Consider following example.

```
bool sym_a[][]={{...},{...},...};  //consider these are initialized properly
bool sym_b[][]={{...},{...},...};
...
bool sym_z[][]={{...},{...},...};
bool sym_0[][]={{...},{...},...};
bool sym_1[][]={{...},{...},...};
...
bool sym_9[][]={{...},{...},...};
...
```

Note the naming convention, all the names are alike. Only the last character of the array name changes (better if it can be more than one character, but that's not important).

Alright, now I have a function. It selects one of those 2D arrays according its passed argument. Then do some task with the selected array. Note that task is a common one, only the selected array gets changed.

For example, according to what I can currently think of, yeah switch-case, I can implement the function as below.

```
void doStuff(char letter){
    switch(letter){
        case 'a':
            sym_a[0][0]=1;  //just for demonstration :D
        break;
        case 'b':
            sym_b[0][0]=1;  //same thing, only the character 'a' changed to 'b'
        break;
        ...
        case 'z':
            sym_z[0][0]=1;
        break;
        case '0':
            sym_0[0][0]=1;
        break;
        case '1':
            sym_1[0][0]=1;
        break;
        ...
        ...
    }    
}
```

But there must be a better way. If i have 1000 such arrays, then do I have to write 1000 such cases?? For all the cases, content is exactly the same. Only one character of a variable name gets changed.

It would be nice if there's something like string concatenation.

```
#define conc(a,b) a ## b
```

Then `conc(sym_,a)` will represent `sym_a`. But that can't be directly applied here. Because i can't pass the exact letter to the right side argument of `conc(a,b)`, only the variable which contain the desired letter can be passed.

```
void doStuff(char letter){
    conc(sym_,letter)[0][0]=1;
}
```

`conc(sym_,letter)` gives `sym_letter`. But i need to concatenate `sym_` with the content of  the character variable `letter`.

For example, if i call `doStuff('b');` them `sym_b` should be given, instead of `sym_letter`.

Hope my requirement clear. This thing seems pretty simple but I can't think of way to get rid of this. Note that the sizes (number of rows/columns) of the 2D arrays are not fixed. Otherwise i could have used a 3D array.

Any thought is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need so many 2D variables alive all the time?

Comment: I dont think C language have bool data type. You can create a single int array and store all your bool data, using bit shift operator.

Comment: @akshay202 well, they are not `alive` all the time (what did you mean?). they are like, hard-coded in the program and considered only when needed. guess that's not a problem anyway. but do you see any better option?
And the above code is what i'm currently using (yeah it works). But i need a simple alternative

Comment: By alive i meant, Do you really need memory for all these arrays to remain allocated all the the time, Are you not wasting memory?

Comment: "I have a large number of 2D arrays (sizes are not fixed). Consider following example.

bool sym_a[][];" This is not possible in C. An array must have a size fixed at compile time, because the size is part of the array's type.

Comment: @newacct yeah, sorry that's a mistake. i wrote so just to give an idea about the names. Actually those arrays are initialized at the the same time, but the sizes will be different. I'll update the question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You have a large number of static arrays, so it' probably a natural extension that you'll end up having a large number of conditionals to access them.

You could define an additional static array that maps the character code to an array.

```
static const struct {
  char* lookup_code;
  bool **array;
} char_code_lookup[] = {
    { .lookup_code = "a", sym_a },
    { .lookup_code = "b", sym_b },
    /* ... */
    { .lookup_code = NULL, NULL }, /* Terminator */
};
```

Your `doStuff` function could then scan the array looking for the appropriate lookup code to match with the statically defined array.

With a bit of macro magic, you could generate both the static arrays, and the static lookup array together to reduce duplication, but the approach listed above is probably easier to read.

Alternatively, you could allocate your arrays dynamically using `malloc`, and at the same time associate a lookup code at the time the array is created at run time.

Comment: If there are really `1000` such arrays (implying wide characters), as written this might be a bit slow. Could either then `qsort` to allow a binary search, or more likely redesign a little to allow a direct jump (depending on details of the look up codes.)

Comment: True, an implementation like this will be slow.  As shown there will be a `strcmp` for each lookup code until a match is found.  An improved design could allocate the arrays dynamically and associate the lookup key with a hash value, allowing O(1) hash lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this help? [ Apologies if there's some C++ here. ]

```
bool** sym_a;
bool** sym_b ;
bool** sym_z;
bool** sym_0;
bool** sym_1;
bool** sym_9 ;


unsigned lowestEntry = 'a';
unsigned highestEntry = '9';
const unsigned numEntries = highestEntry - lowestEntry;

size_t size = sizeof(bool**)* numEntries;

bool*** lookup = (bool***)malloc(size); 

#define conc(a,b) a ## b
#define index(a) #a[0]-'a'
#define add(a) lookup[index(a)] = conc(sym_,a)

void init()
{
    memset(lookup, 0, size);
     add(a);
     add(b);
     add(z);
     add(9);
     add(k); // does not compile, sym_k not defined.
}

bool** findSymbolTable(char val)
{
    return lookup[val - lowestEntry];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Allocate an large int array and partition it for your other variables.

eg.

int data[2600];

will have first 100 integers for sym_a next 100 for sym_b and so on. You will be able to store 8 * 100* 4 boolean values in these arrays.

now to access sym_p[x][y] you will say is you have total R rows and C columns:

int * start = data + (ASCIValue(p) - ASCIValue(a)) * 100;

You wud have to read/write bit number (C * x + y) from start.